# usermodel is accessible from more than one module poi, poi.examples

Tags: apache, jar, apache-poi

I am getting an error on lines 9, 11, 13, 15 17 - The package `org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel` is accessible from more than one module poi, poi.examples. I downloaded the latest poi jars and added them to module path. Please let me know where I went wrong?

```
package apachetests;

import java.io.File;

import java.io.FileInputStream;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook;

import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

public class Writetoexcel {

    public static void main(String []args){

        try {

            // Specify the file path which you want to create or write

            File src=new File("C:\\Users\\Venkat\\Desktop\\Hima2017\\Names.xlsx");

            // Load the file

            FileInputStream fis=new FileInputStream(src);

            // load the workbook

            XSSFWorkbook wb=new XSSFWorkbook(fis);

            // get the sheet which you want to modify or create

            XSSFSheet sh1= wb.getSheetAt(0);

            // getRow specify which row we want to read and getCell which column

            System.out.println(sh1.getRow(0).getCell(0).getStringCellValue());

            System.out.println(sh1.getRow(0).getCell(1).getStringCellValue());

            System.out.println(sh1.getRow(1).getCell(0).getStringCellValue());

            System.out.println(sh1.getRow(1).getCell(1).getStringCellValue());

            System.out.println(sh1.getRow(2).getCell(0).getStringCellValue());

            System.out.println(sh1.getRow(2).getCell(1).getStringCellValue());

            // here createCell will create column

            // and setCellvalue will set the value

            sh1.getRow(0).createCell(2).setCellValue("2.41.0");

            sh1.getRow(1).createCell(2).setCellValue("2.5");

            sh1.getRow(2).createCell(2).setCellValue("2.39");


            // here we need to specify where you want to save file

            FileOutputStream fout=new FileOutputStream(new File("location of file/filename.xlsx"));


            // finally write content

            wb.write(fout);

            // close the file

            fout.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {

            System.out.println(e.getMessage());

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: The imports in the lines you mentioned aren't used. Apart of this please check the [POI FAQ for Java 9](http://poi.apache.org/faq.html#faq-N102B0)

Comment: Don't put them on the module path! Just put them (and their dependencies) on the *classpath* and all will be fine, the module path stuff is a mess

Comment: Added the jar files on classpath still getting the following error -  Unresolved compilation problems: 
 XSSFWorkbook cannot be resolved to a type
 XSSFWorkbook cannot be resolved to a type
 XSSFSheet cannot be resolved to a type

Comment: I am not using Maven so no dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

This is solved with the latest release.

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
```